# Fail to run unit test at react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I wanna run unit test at react, but when I run "npm test", it shows me this error:

```
navList.test.js: Unexpected token (12:26)
> 12 |         let app = shallow(<NavList/>);
     |                           ^
```

Following is my code:

**navList.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow, configure} from 'enzyme';
import {expect} from 'chai';
import {NavList} from '../components/common/nav/navList';

import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe('NavList', function () {
    it('NavList ', function () {
        let app = shallow(<NavList/>);
        expect(app.find('h2').length).to.equal(1);
    });
});
```

**package.json**:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-jest": "^22.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "jest": "^22.1.4",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mocha": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0"
  }
```

Did I miss something at install ?

Comment: have you simply tried NavList in shallow?

Comment: @GauravPaliwal Did you mean use "shallow(<NavList/>);" instead of "describe('NavList', function () { ... });"?
I did it, and I got same error massage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the code isn't getting transpiled before jest is trying to run it (hence the `Unexpected token` error).

Take a look at the setup instructions [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react.html#setup-without-create-react-app). My best guess is that you need to update your `.babelrc` with the `react` preset.